# Atualizar apenas os registros marcados com checkbox de uma vez php

Tags: php, mysqli, checkbox, sql-update

Tenho um select que traz uma série de registros. Eis que, nesses registros eu preciso aplicar uma up e que, na minha cabeça, a melhor maneira seria utilizando um campo checkbox, para que, quando o usuário marcasse o checkbox e, em seguida, clicasse no botão "enviar", somente o campo do checkbox- de todos os registros - seriam atualizados ao mesmo tempo (com 1ou 2 dependendo se o campo foi marcado 1 ou não 2). Espe.. Grato pela ajuda! To quebrando a cabeça aqui e nunca consigo tenho pesquisado e perguntado e não obtive respostas conclusivas

form.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);
$idEvent = $_POST['idsubev'];
?>
<?php
//
$sql = "SELECT u.nome, e.titulo, a.presente, a.id_al FROM sch_usuarios u INNER JOIN sch_acontecimentos e INNER JOIN sch_aluno_acont a WHERE e.id_acon = a.id_acon AND u.id = a.id_al AND e.id_subevent='$idEvent' ORDER BY u.nome";

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

echo "
<form method='post' action = 'update.php' >
   <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$rows['id_al']."'>
   <h1> Alterar presença do aluno</h1>
   <table align='' border='0' bordercolor='#BCBCBC' cellspacing='0'>
    <tr align ='left' bordercolor='#000000' >
        <td valign='middle'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td valign='middle'>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align ='left' bordercolor='#000000' ><td valign='middle' bgcolor='#E9E9E9'><p><font color=''>Nome:</font> </p></td>
        <td align='left' valign='middle' bgcolor='#E9E9E9'><input type = 'text' size='50' name='nome' value ='".$rows['nome']."'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><font color=''> Curso: </font> </td>
        <td align='left'><input type='text' size='30' name='curso' value=' ".$rows['titulo']."'><font color=''> </font>
        </td>
    <tr align ='left'>

    //QUERO ATUALIZAR ESSE CAMPOS ABAIXO CHAMADO PRESENTE
        <td><font color=''>Presente=<b>".$rows['presente']."</b> </font></td>
        <td align='left'>

            //AQUI MARCAREI O CHECKBOX NOS ALUNOS QUE QUERO MUDAR PARA 1 (PRESENTE)
            Status 1= presente, 2= ausente    
            <input type='checkbox' name='presente' value='1'>
<input type='checkbox' name='presente' value='2'>
Marcar Presente? 
        </td>
     </tr>
</table>

"; /*fecha a tabela apos termino de impressão das linhas*/
}

echo "<input type='submit' value='alterar'>
</form>";
?>
```

Update.php

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
$presente = $_POST['presente'];
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'wwwcard_ew3', 'adm22334455', 'wwwcard_ew3');

$sql = "UPDATE sch_aluno_acont SET presente = '$presente' WHERE id_al = '$id'";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) or die($mysqli->error);

if(!$stmt){
  echo 'erro na consulta: '. $mysqli->errno .' - '. $mysqli->error;
}

$stmt->bind_param('ssi',$id, $presente);
$stmt->execute();

header("Location: index.php?
```

Comment: Você está criando um formulário por aluno, não correto

Comment: Preciso de ajuda nisso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, trata-se de uma lista de presença dos alunos.

Sugestão para esta primeira solução: no banco coluna `presente` como `Default Value` igual a 2, dai só seria necessário fazer  `update` para os presentes, bastando então, somente um checkbox que seria marcado caso o aluno esteja presente.

Os values dos checkboxes  são os `id_al` vindos da consulta que serão usados na clausula `where` no update da coluna `presente` com valor `1` dos checkboxes marcados.

**form.php**

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "NOME_DB");
$idEvent = $_POST['idsubev'];

$sql = "SELECT ....................
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

echo "<form method='post' action = 'Update.php' >

<h1> Alterar presença do aluno</h1>
<table align='' border='0' bordercolor='#BCBCBC' cellspacing='0'>
<tr align ='left' bordercolor='#000000' >
    <td valign='middle'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td valign='middle'>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>";


while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    echo "<tr align ='left' bordercolor='#000000' ><td valign='middle' bgcolor='#E9E9E9'><p><font color=''>Nome:</font> </p></td>
        <td align='left' valign='middle' bgcolor='#E9E9E9'>".$rows['nome']."</td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td><font color=''> Curso: </font> </td>
        <td align='left'>".$rows['titulo']."</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align ='left'>
        <td><font color=''>Presente=<b>presente</b> </font></td>
        <td align='left'>
            Status marcado = presente <input type='checkbox' name='presente[]' value='".$rows['id_al']."'>Marcar Presente?
        </td>
     </tr>";

}

echo "</table>
<input type='submit' value='alterar'>
</form>";

?>
```

**Update.php**

```
<?php

$presente = $_POST['presente'];

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "NOME_DB");

$sql = 'UPDATE sch_aluno_acont SET presente = 1 WHERE id_al IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval', $presente)) . ')';
$data = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

?>
```

---

---

### Para fazer update de todos os checkboxes marcados ou não marcados

Nesta solução não há necessidade da coluna `presente` ser `Default Value`

**form.php**

```
.............................
.............................
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {

    echo "<tr align ='left' bordercolor='#000000' ><td valign='middle' bgcolor='#E9E9E9'><p><font color=''>Nome:</font> </p></td>
        <td align='left' valign='middle' bgcolor='#E9E9E9'>".$rows['nome']."</td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td><font color=''> Curso: </font> </td>
        <td align='left'>".$rows['titulo']."</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align ='left'>
        <td><font color=''>Presente=<b>presente</b> </font></td>
        <td align='left'>
            Status marcado = presente <input type='checkbox' name='presente[]' value='".$rows['id_al']."'>
Marcar Presente?
        </td>
     </tr>";
 //todos os id_al 
 $all_id_al .=$rows['id_al'].",";   
}

echo "<input type='hidden' name='all_id_al' value='".substr($all_id_al, 0, -1)."'>";

echo "</table><input type='submit' value='alterar'></form>";

?>
```

**Update.php**

```
<?php

$presente = $_POST['presente'];

$all_id_al = $_POST['all_id_al'];

$all_id = explode(",",$all_id_al);

$result=array_diff($all_id,$presente);

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "NOME_DB");

//marcados
$sql = 'UPDATE sch_aluno_acont SET presente = 1 WHERE id_al IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval', $presente)) . ')';
$data = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

//não marcados
$sql2 = 'UPDATE sch_aluno_acont SET presente = 2 WHERE id_al IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval', $result)) . ')';
$data2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

?>
```

> do formulário vem uma string com todos os `id_al` que transformamos em um array  `$all_id`.
>
> `$result=array_diff($all_id,$presente);` retorna os valores de `$all_id` que não estão presentes em `$presente` e que serão utilizados para o update dos checkboxes não marcados.

Comment: Exatamente a solução 1 que eu precisava so para marcar os presentes, vou testar e te falo, Leo seria possivel na pagina form implementar uma paginacao antes de dar o submit, pois tem bastante registros, muito obrigado

Comment: Ola Leo, deu certo da forma que voce fez porem estou com outro problema, : tem alunos que estao matriculados em varios cursos, ou seja o id do aluno é o mesmo , mas o id do curso na coluna id_curso, é diferente para cada id do usuario, entao cada vez que uso o o script e marco um aluno que tenha mais de um curso o script atualiza todas as linha dos outros cursos tambem onde o id do usuario é igual

Comment: @Claudio sem ver a estrutura da tabela fica complicado, acho que um `AND` na clausula where resolveria seu problema, mas como eu disse, sem ver a estrutura fica complicado

Comment: segueCREATE TABLE `sch_aluno_acont` (
  `id_al` bigint(14) NOT NULL,
  `id_acon` bigint(14) NOT NULL,
  `presente` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pago` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `sch_aluno_acont`
--

INSERT INTO `sch_aluno_acont` (`id_al`, `id_acon`, `presente`, `pago`) VALUES
(100242, 171007074752, 2, 1),
(100242, 171007074838, 2, 2),
(100242, 171020141939, 2, 1);

Comment: coloquei um input hidden com  o id_acon e fiz um AND no update certinho com o implode mesma coisa do id_al, porem nao adiantou...

Comment: tem que ver isso com calma porque agora tem mais opções que seriam os cursos e isto não está no HTML

Comment: Ok fico no aguardo muito obrigado

Comment: @Claudio, é melhor fazer outra pergunta com a nova situação para que esse a resposta não fique fora do foco da pergunta. Se essa resposta atendeu plenamente a sua pergunta original  marque-a como aceita, veja como e o porque nesse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: @Claudio, estou esperando você postar a nova pergunta com a nova situação para postar a resposta que fiz. Assim que vc postar deixe um comentário aqui pra eu saber e procurar por ela

Comment: Segue link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/253401/atualizar-campo-de-tabela-apenas-marcados-com-checkbox-php-mysql