# Atualizar campo de tabela apenas marcados com checkbox php mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, checkbox, sql-update

@Leo Caracciolo deu certo da forma que você fez  [**nesse post aqui**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/253036/atualizar-apenas-os-registros-marcados-com-checkbox-de-uma-vez-php/253073?noredirect=1#comment520033_253073), porém estou com outro problema: tem alunos que estão matriculados em vários cursos, ou seja o id do aluno é o mesmo , mas o id do curso na coluna id_curso, é diferente para cada id do usuário, então cada vez que uso o o script e marco um aluno que tenha mais de um curso o script atualiza todas as linha dos outros cursos também onde o id do usuário é igual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**form.php**

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "NOME_DB");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM sch_aluno_acont";
    $data = mysqli_query($conn, $query);


    echo "<form method='post' action = 'update2.php' >

    <h1> Alterar presença do aluno</h1>
    <table align='' border='0' bordercolor='#BCBCBC' cellspacing='0'>
    <tr align ='left' bordercolor='#000000'>
        <td colspan='2' valign='middle'><font color=''>Marque o(s) curso(s) para <b>presença</b> </font><br></td>
    </tr>";

$id_al_Old="zzz";
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {
    if ($rows['id_al']!=$id_al_Old) {

         if ($id_al_Old!="zzz") {  
            echo "</td>";      
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "<tr align ='left' bordercolor='#000000'>
        <td valign='middle' bgcolor='#E9E9E9'><p><font color=''>Nome:</font>".$rows['nome']." </p></td>
        <td align='left' valign='middle' bgcolor='#E9E9E9'>".$rows['titulo']."</td>
        </tr>

        <tr align ='left'>
        <td colspan='2' align='left'>";
    }
        echo "curso ".$rows['id_acon']."
        <input type='checkbox' name='presente[]' value='".$rows['id_al']."*".$rows['id_acon']."'>";

        $id_al_Old=$rows['id_al'];
}

    echo "</td></tr></table><input type='submit' value='alterar'></form>";
?>
```

**Update.php**

```
<?php

$presente = $_POST['presente'];

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "NOME_DB");

foreach ($presente as $value) {
    $parte=explode("*",$value);

    $sql = "UPDATE sch_aluno_acont SET presente = 1 WHERE id_al='$parte[0]' and id_acon='$parte[1]'";
    $data = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}


?>
```

---

### Explicando a lógica

Na pagina `form.php` inserimos no value dos `input type='checkbox'` os valores retornados da consulta de `id_al` e `id_acon` separados por um asteristico (*).

```
<input type='checkbox' name='presente[]' value='".$rows['id_al']."*".$rows['id_acon']."'>";
```

Repare que no name do input foi acrescentado dois colchetes `[ ]`

```
name='presente[]'
```

Quando você coloca um "name" com colchetes ele é enviado na forma de array para o receptor.

Na pagina `Update.php`

Resgatamos os dados vindo do formulário (array)  `$presente = $_POST['presente'];`

Com `foreach ($presente as $value) {`, temos que a cada iteração, o valor do elemento atual é atribuído a $value, por exemplo `100244*171007074752`

de posse desse valor fazemos um `explode` e colocamos as devidas partes na condição `where` do update `WHERE id_al='$parte[0]' and id_acon='$parte[1]'"`

> foi feita uma correção no arquivo `form.php` para que a saída em `html` esteja correta.

Comment: cara perfeito voce é otimo amigao, nem sei como te agradecer, se possivel me explicar a logica ai pq fiquei boiando nisso.... forte abraço e muito obrigado

Comment: @Claudio não precisa agradecer, marque as respostas como aceitas  veja como e porque https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: deixe seu contato para bater um papo, estou começando a estudar php a fundo e com essas dicas vou decolar kkk

Comment: Bom dia Léo,  poderia me explicar a lógica dos arquivos.

Comment: @Claudio espero que a explicação esteja fácil de entender :)

Comment: Perfeito valeu!!!!!